# XML Replace node value

Tags: xml, t-sql

I am trying to update XML node and while it does not generate an error it does not update the value.

the xml

```
    <ParameterValues>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>TO</Name>
    <Value>test@test.com.au</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>IncludeReport</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>RenderFormat</Name>
    <Value>MHTML</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>Subject</Name>
    <Value>@ReportName was executed at @ExecutionTime</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>IncludeLink</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>Priority</Name>
    <Value>NORMAL</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

The update string.

1. (This is what Im tring to change -  `<Value>test@test.com.au</Value>` )

   set @input.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Name/Value/ text())[1] with "D.1234@EEEER.COM.AU"')

If I change the string to update the Name node it updates with "D.1234@EEEER.COM.AU"?

1.`<Name>TO</Name>`

set @input.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Name/  text())[1] with "D.1234@EEEER.COM.AU"')

Example result

```
<ParameterValues>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>D.1234@EEEER.COM.AU</Name>
    <Value>d.brown@orrcon.com.au</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What's the language or tool `set` is executed in?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention where I was doing this. TSQL. What I have tried is :- set @input.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Name/Value/ text())[1] with "D.1234@EEEER.COM.AU"')

Comment: Please add `TSQL` to your question tags so experts of that field can help you instead. xP

Answer (score 1):

all you want sir is to update... try use this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( xml file name );

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->getElementsByTagName("Value")->item(0)->nodeValue = $TheNewValue; 
$doc->save("pathwheroverwritethefile");
```

i wish i could help.... i think the array value on item is the error...

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `Name` node specified in your update statement.

Try this instead to replace the value of the first `ParameterValue`node.

```sql
replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value/text())[1] 
                    with "D.1234@EEEER.COM.AU"
```

If you want to make sure that you only replace the value of the `ParameterValue` where `Name` is `TO` you should use a predicate on the `ParameterValue` node.

```sql
replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name = "TO"]/Value/text())[1] 
                    with "D.1234@EEEER.COM.AU"')
```

Comment: Thank you. I new it was simple but couldnt see the trees for the forrest.